# How to Script Table in SQL Server to get data along with schema

Tags: sql-server, schema

Is there any option to script table to get not only table design but also DATA. I couldn't find any option. Could any one assist me in getting data from table using Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try 
Right Click on db => Tasks => Generate Scripts => In "Set Scripting Options: Click Advanced, find Types of data to script. You can choose between Data only, Script and data and Schema only. The default is Schema only